# How to check if the stack is empty on 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, microprocessors, emu8086

I am working on a study in Assembler 8086 that checks the balance of the parenthesis in a mathematical expression. The algorithm is as follows:

- Make an empty stack
- Read characters until end of string
- If the character is an opening symbol, push it onto stack
- If it is a closing symbol, then if the stack is empty report an error, otherwise, pop the stack
- If the symbol popped is not the corresponding opening symbol, then report an error
- At end of file, if the stack is not empty report an error

I have figured out all the parts except the part that I need to check if the stack is empty. How can I check if the stack is empty or how can I create an empty stack in the code? When there is nothing left to pop in the stack, I try to pop it and some value comes out. What does that value mean?

Comment: When you make an empty stack, it has a starting address. When you push things on the stack, the address decreases. When you pop them off, the address increases. Your stack is empty when the address reaches the original address you started with when the stack was empty.

Comment: You can also push a value on the stack as an “end of stack” marker and check if you popped that value.

Comment: I think pushing a marker value to the stack is going to solve my problem. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: A marker would work well if your set of symbols doesn't use all of the possible values that can be pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to use the call-stack to implement your stack data structure.  This is normal and often a good idea in asm.

You don't want to "empty" the call stack, you just want to set up a way to tell when you've popped all the data you pushed *in this function*.  i.e. that your stack data structure is empty.

Either push a sentinel value that your code doesn't otherwise generate, or use a register (or memory location) to save the current value of SP.  Especially in 16-bit code, it's very common to use `mov bp,sp` to make a stack frame, so you are already dedicating a register to remembering an old value of SP.  You can use `cmp sp,bp` in later code to see if you've emptied your stack data structure.

If you need any space for locals on the stack, you could set up your stack frame with space for locals above BP, and your variable sized stack data below BP.

```
 my_func:
    ; push  si   ; save whatever other register you want
    sub   sp, 28      ; reserve 28 bytes for locals
    push  bp
    mov   bp, sp

  .my_loop:
    ...                ; use locals from [bp+2] to [bp+26]
    cmp  bp, sp
    jne   .my_loop
    ; else fall through: stack empty

    leave
    add   sp, 28
    ret
```

If you don't need to spill any local variables to memory at all, then you don't need to make a stack frame and can use `bp` as an extra scratch register.  But if you do, then you can use `bp` as the top of your stack data structure for free.

Note that it's not quite a traditional stack frame: normally `[bp+2]` is the return address, so debugger stack backtraces might show bogus results.  But `[bp+0]` is still pointing at the caller's saved `bp` value, so only that entry will be wrong, and it won't break backtracing *through* this function.

---

**What would it mean for the call stack to be empty?**

There's always memory above `ss:sp` unless `sp = 0xFFFE` (2 byte aligned at the top of a segment).  [`pop`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/POP.html) doesn't even fault if `sp` wraps around from `0xFFFE` to `0x0000`.  `pop [mem]` can `#GP` if popping into memory outside the segment limit of CS, DS, ES, FS, or GS, according to the manual, but I think that's only possible in unreal mode.

[`push` in real-mode does fault with `#SS`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html) if the new value of `sp` or `esp` is outside the stack segment limit (impossible in pure x86-16 without using unreal mode cached segment descriptors loaded in protected mode).  Actually I think you could maybe get a #SS in pure real-mode with `SP=1` / `push ax`.  The store address would be `ss:0xFFFF`, and thus the 2-byte store would include memory 1 byte outside the 64k segment starting at `ss<<4`

Comment: Your last paragraph is correct. Having `SP=1` and doing a `push` or having `SP=0xffff` and doing a `pop` will generate a `#SS` due to writing (resp. reading) 1 byte outside the `SS` segment. Fun fact: since there is no stack switching in real mode an `#SS` of this kind will generate a triple fault, resetting the CPU (i.e rebooting).

Comment: I highly doubt he should use a hardware stack. Instead, a separate one is usually utilized for such role.

Comment: @Netch: In C yes, because C doesn't expose that ASM feature.  So you often end up with a VLA or `alloca` with some up-front size, and you use that for your stack data structure.  But in asm, you can `alloca` one stack-slot at a time for free *and reclaim the space as you `pop`*.